# Few confusing things about globally accessible Value Objects

Tags: domain-driven-design

Quotes are from [DDD: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) ( pg. 150 )

a)

> global search access to a VALUE is often meaningles, because finding a
>   VALUE by its properties would be equivalent to creating a new instance
>   with those properties. There are exceptions. For example, when I am
>   planning travel online, I sometimes save a few prospective itineraries
>   and return later to select one to book. Those itineraries are VALUES
>   (if there were two made up of the same flights, I would not care which
>   was which), but they have been associated with my user name and
>   retrieved for me intact.

I don't understand author's reasoning as for why it would be more appropriate to make `Itinierary` Value Object globally accessible instead of clients having to globally search for `Customer root entity` and then traverse from it to this `Itinierary` object?

b)

> A subset of persistent objects must be globaly accessible through a
>   search based on object attributes ... They are usualy ENTITIES,
>   sometimes VALUE OBJECTS with complex internal structure ...

Why is it more common for *Values Objects with complex internal structure* to be globally accesible rather than simpler *Value Objects*?

c) Anyways,  are there some general guidelines on how to determine whether a particular Value Object should be made globally accessible?

**UPDATE:**

a)

> There is no domain reason to make an itinerary traverse-able through
>   the customer entity. Why load the customer entity if it isn't needed
>   for any behavior? Queries are usually best handled without
>   complicating the behavioral domain.

I'm probably wrong about this,  but isn't it common that when user ( Ie Customer root entity ) logs in, *domain model* retrieves user's `Customer Aggregate`?

And if users have an option to book flights, then it would also be common for them to check from time to time the `Itineraries` ( though English isn't my first language so the term `Itinerary` may actually mean something a bit different than I think it means ) they have selected or booked.

And since `Customer Aggregate` is already retrieved from the DB, why issue another global search for `Itinerary` ( which will probably search for it in DB ) when it was already retrieved together with `Customer Aggregate`?

c)

> The rule is quite simple IMO - if there is a need for it. It doesn't
>   depend on the structure of the VO itself but on whether an instance of
>   a particular VO is needed for a use case.

But this VO instance has to be related to some entity ( ie `Itinerary` is related to particular `Customer` ), else as the author pointed out, instead of searching for VO by its properties, we could simply create a new VO instance with those properties?

**SECOND UPDATE:**

a) From your [link](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/24/implementing-associations-with-references-or-repositories-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/):

> Another method for expressing relationships is with a repository.

When relationship is expressed via *repository*, do you implement a `SalesOrder.LineItems` property ( which I doubt, since you advise against entities calling repositories directly ), which in turns calls a *repository*, or do you implement something like `SalesOrder.MyLineItems(IOrderRepository repo)`? If the latter, then I assume there is no need for `SalesOrder.LineItems` property?

b)

> The important thing to remember is that aggregates aren't meant to be
>   used for displaying data.

True that *domain model* doesn't care what upper layers will do with the data, but if not using DTO's between *Application* and *UI* layers, then I'd assume *UI* will extract the data to display from an *aggregate* ( assuming we sent to UI whole aggregate and not just some entity residing within it )?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) There is no domain reason to make an itinerary traverse-able through the customer entity. Why load the customer entity if it isn't needed for any behavior? Queries are usually best handled without complicating the behavioral domain.

b) I assume that his reasoning is that complex value objects are those that you want to query since you can't easily recreate them. This issue and all query related issues can be addressed with the [read-model pattern](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/).

c) The rule is quite simple IMO - if there is a need for it. It doesn't depend on the structure of the VO itself but on whether an instance of a particular VO is needed for a use case.

**UPDATE**

a) It is unlikely that a customer aggregate would have references to the customer's itineraries. The reason is that I don't see how an itinerary would be related to behaviors that would exist in the customer aggregate. It is also unnecessary to load the customer aggregate at all if all that is needed is some data to display. However, if you do load the aggregate and it does contain reference data that you need you may as well display it. The important thing to remember is that aggregates aren't meant to be used for displaying data.

c) The relationship between customer and itinerary could be expressed by a shared ID - each itinerary would have a customerId. This would allow lookup as required. However, just because these two things are related it does not mean that you need to traverse customer to get to the related entities or value objects for viewing purposes. More generally, associations can be implemented either as [direct references or via repository search](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/24/implementing-associations-with-references-or-repositories-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/). There are trade-offs either way.

**UPDATE 2**

a) If implemented with a repository, there is no `LineItems` property - no direct references. Instead, to obtain a list of line items a repository is called.

b) Or you can create a DTO-like object, a read-model, which would be returned directly from the repository. The repository can in turn execute a simple SQL query to get all required data. This allows you to get to data that isn't part of the aggregate but is related. If an aggregate does have all the data needed for a view, then use that aggregate. But as soon as you have a need for more data that doesn't concern the aggregate, switch to a read-model.

Comment: A - So SalesOrder.MyLineItems(IOrderRepository repo) would a good approach? B - Off topic, but would calling SalesOrder.MyLineItems(IOrderRepository repo) also be considered as traversing an association or is the term used only when calling SalesOrder.LineItems property?

Comment: Why do you need a MyLineItems method at all? Is there behavior on SalesOrder that needs line items?

Comment: Ok, a bad example since probably SalesOrder itself isn't a root, but instead lives inside Customer Aggregate and LineItems conceptually don't belong to Customer aggregate ( I'm assuming the term LineItem means an item to purchase ).

Comment: I would think that SalesOrder is the root of the SaleOrder aggregate. Customer is yet another aggregate.

Comment: They shold be both roots because the concept of Customer isn't tied up to the concept of SalesOrder? But my reasoning was that SalesOrder can't exist without some sort of customer? uh,I'm really bad at this

Comment: You could require a customer for a sale order, but you only need an ID, not a reference to entire aggregate object. In other words, you can have cross-aggregate references, but it is best to have them be by ID only.

Comment: In some instances it might actually be acceptable to have a sales order without a customer which awaits customer data to be populated, but this is part of a more complex scenario. Take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/aa699424.aspx).

Comment: ok, last question since I've taken enough of your time - I thought that usually aggregates wrap within also those objects that wouldn't make sense on their own? Thus, if some object O can't exist without another object (just like breathing can't exist without a living entity or as SalesOrder doesn't make sense without some Customer making an order), then I assumed that object O in most cases shouldn't exist on its own as a root? What am I not seeing?

Comment: That is true of value objects - they don't make sense outside of an entity. Just because an entity A depends on the existence of another entity B, does not mean that A cannot be an aggregate root. In fact, it is often advisable to consider the context under which an aggregate is created - [Don't Create Aggregate Roots](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/).

Comment: Aggregates provide a logical grouping of Entities and Value Objects that belong together at all times and as such used as unit. In this way it ensures a consistency. But you're telling me that even if a particular entity can't exist without another entity, it doesn't necessarily mean that the two entities always need to be treated as a unit, thus their states (ie their data changes) don't necessarily need to be consistent/synchronized whenever one of the entities is updated?

Comment: Yes. Take for instance the sales order example. While a sales order cannot exist without a customer, a customer can certainly exist without a sales order. If there is data exchange of any sort between two different aggregates, such as customer and order, these changes can be made consistent via events. Typically this is done in an async fashion hence _eventual_ consistency.

Comment: But when Customer does get deleted, Order too must get deleted. I assume in such cases there must be an Invariant rule spanning both aggregates, which would also make sure that Order gets deleted within the same transaction as Customer ( this question is assuming that this is not one of those complex scenarios you previously mentioned where Order can exist without a Customer )?!

Comment: The order does not _have_ to be deleted in the same transaction. It could be deleted in an eventually consistent manner.

Comment: thank you for helping and apologies for dragging this for so long